# Sql combine first and last value of a column to create a range to third column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
 WeekId  CalendarDate
 200     1993-06-26 00:00:00
 200     1993-06-27 00:00:00
 200     1993-06-28 00:00:00
 200     1993-06-29 00:00:00
 200     1993-06-30 00:00:00
 200     1993-07-01 00:00:00
 201     1993-10-02 00:00:00
 ...     ...................
 ...     ...................
```

I want to create a separate column here called **weekRange** that takes the first calendar date for the weekId and the last calendar date for the same week Id and have the result as :

For ex: for weekId 200 the weekRange would be

```
1993-06-26 00:00:00 - 1993-07-01 00:00:00
```

Any help here is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inner join on subquery for min and max  by weekId

```
  select m.WeekId, m.calendarDate, concat(t.min_date, ' - ' , t.max_date )
  from my_table m  
  inner join  (
      select  weekId 
      , min(calendarDate) min_date
          , max(calendarDate) max_date 
      from my_table  
      group by weekId 
  ) t on t.weekId = m.weekId
```

once you have altered  the table adding the weekRange columns (as  varchar)  ..
you could use an update

```
  update my_table  m1 
  inner join  (

      select  weekId 
      , min(calendarDate) min_date
          , max(calendarDate) max_date 
      from my_table  
      group by weekId 
  ) t on t.weekId = m1.weekId 
  set  m1.weekRange  = concat(t.min_date, ' - ' , t.max_date )
```

and for date format as in your comment

update my_table  m1 
  inner join  (

```
  select  weekId 
  , min(calendarDate) min_date
      , max(calendarDate) max_date 
  from my_table  
  group by weekId 
  ) t on t.weekId = m1.weekId 
 set  m1.weekRange  = concat(date_forma(t.min_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), 
        ' - ' , date_forma(t.max_date, '%m-%d-%Y') )
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply . How can i create a new column with these values in the same table ?

Comment: asnwer updated ..  hope you are able to alter the table for adding the column .. otherwise  let me know

Comment: Thanks a ton. What would it take to format it to 06/26/1993 - 07-02-1993 rather than Jul  3 1993 12:00AM - Jul  9 1993 12:00AM . ?. Appreciate all the help since i am new to sql

Comment: for date format conversion  .. you can take a look at mysql function str_To_date  and date_format

Comment: I was able to figure out the format but however with the update code i get its syntactically wrong .. (incorrect syntax near inner) and (incorrect syntax near t)